# Prolong the lifespan of dslr shoe mount

Tags: hotshoe-flash, adapter, hotshoe

We are planning to use an external microphone that mounts via shoe mount. The concern is that due continuous mount / dismount procedures we may spoil the shoe mount on the camera one day. In order to prevent this we wonder if there are some solutions, like "mount in mount" adapter so that if one day it spoils we can just replace the adapter and don't worry about the camera itself.

The closest example I can think of, are the USB magnetic cables. You can simply stick the connector in your device and leave it there, so that upon multiple cable attachments the port on the device doesn't suffer from the physical interactions.

Comment: Be aware of affect of "stack height" on wobble and force on camera-shoe when using adapters. Worst case you may possibly compound the problem you are trying to fix. A locking show such as Michael shows in his 1st image probably transfers force onto the camera show-surround which may be robust enough to withstand long term forces. || If your microphone is using the camera-show only as a mount and not for electrical connection, consider using an L bracket connected to the camera's lower tripod mount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not the primary purpose for which it is designed, something like this [Hot Shoe-to-PC adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0032CAGH0) will probably do what you want. Get it in whichever version matches your camera's hot shoe pin pattern and you can also use it for the rare occasion when you want to use a TTL flash or a *PC Terminal¹* connected flash without removing your adapter.

[image: Hot Shoe-to-PC adapter,]

<sub>¹PC in the context of flash photography has nothing to do with a personal computer. It is an abbreviation of *Prontor/Compur*. Prontor has its origins in the Italian word *pronto* (quick) and was a brand of shutter produced by Alfred Gauthier in the 1950s. *Compur*, derived from the word *compound*, was the shutter brand of the Deckel Company. Both companies were based in Germany and both counted Zeiss as an influential stockholder when they introduced the standard 1/8"-inch coaxial connector for shutter/flash synchronization.</sub>

You can get [something that's a little lower profile](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007BCIIZ4) and doesn't contain any electronics, but there doesn't seem to be any widely available that have a locking foot to keep it (and your microphone) from sliding off your camera's hot shoe.

[image: Cold shoe base]

Beyond that, there are a lot of options that involve building up a rig cage around your camera and attaching accessories to the cage. If you go that route then an adapter like this [SmallRig Cold Shoe Mount Adapter Bracket](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HJFBUCQ) would be the way to go.

[image: SmallRig Cold Shoe Mount Adapter Bracket]